# Copy Table from One Database to another database in the same cluster?

Tags: postgresql

Is there a way to copy table of one database to table of another database within the same cluster?

I have a cluster with multiple database.
I have a **master** Database and multiple **slave** databases .

I will change one table in **master** and i want to copy to remaining database.

Is there a way to do it via ***postgresql console***?

I use the following from the bash.

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U myuser -C -t my_table -d first_db>/tmp/table_dump 

psql -U myuser -d second_db</tmp/table_dump
```

I have to create a temporary dump file.

I use psycopg adapter to manage databases. 
Here I am looking forward for some solution.

Comment: Use a foreign data wrapper: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/postgres-fdw.html

Answer (score 2):

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/19697098/450812, you can create a pipe.

```
pg_dump -h localhost -U myuser -C -t my_table -d first_db | psql -U myuser -d second_db
```

If you need to enter passwords, you can:

```
PGPASSWORD=password1 pg_dump -h localhost -U myuser -C -t my_table -d first_db | PGPASSWORD=password2 psql -U myuser -d second_db
```